# Is it possible to get turn by turn directions using Google Maps Api in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am looking for a way to get or make turn by turn navigation using Google Maps Api in swift. I've done drawing polylines from source to destination using GoogleMaps Api but still couldn't find a way to do turn by turn navigation. Is it possible?

-Thanks

Comment: Did you find solution for this ? is  directions using google API is helpful with this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible.

Please refer following link which is using turn by turn directions using google API.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/biznavi-gets-you-where-you/id597147565?mt=8
(see last two screen shot of iPad from itunes link)

To achieve it, you have to use Google Direction API which allows us to use upto 8 way points.

After that you will get an array of route including all turn by turn message and lat/long.

Just create a CLRegion of 100 meters (or as per your requirement.) around your current location in locationDidUpdate method. If next point of route array falls within CLRegion, just show a message received in routes array by google API.

I have made above application but it was not updated after uploading to store so it is having old UI and it is not having iPhone 5+ support. Sorry for that but you will find feature you require in this app...

Comment: Yes, I think I can set the way points. But it will only point out way points with marker. This is not the solution I am looking for. I am looking for a way which will demonstrate arrows along with the path through which I can navigate from source to destination.